# yesod form set selected values in multi-select field using jquery

Tags: yesod, yesod-forms

Temporarily I'm using **Monadic Form of Yesod** for creating my forms but I'm having a hard time setting values on it using jquery. Since the **Monadic Form** generates form for you, it has its own way to set the values on the select/multi-select field

eg :

```
sampleForm :: Html -> MForm Handler (FormResult (Maybe [Text]), Widget)
sampleForm = renderBootstrap bConfig $ (,)
    <$> aopt (multiSelectFieldList $ colors) "Color" Nothing
  where
    colors :: [(Text, Color)]
    colors = [("Red", Red), ("Blue", Blue), ("Gray", Gray), ("Black", Black)]
```

The output:

```
   <select multiselect>
       <option value="1">Red</option>
       <option value="2">Blue</option>
       <option value="3">Gray</option>
      <option value="4">Black</option>
   </select>
```

What I want is to be like this:

```
<select id="colors" multiselect>
     <option value="Red">Red</option>
     <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
     <option value="Gray">Gray</option>
     <option value="Black">Black</option>
</select>
```

So that in my jquery code:

```
var selectedValues = "Red,Black,Gary";
$.each(selectedValues.split(","), function(i,e){
  $("#colors option[value='" + e.replace(/\s/g, '') + "']").prop("selected", true);
});
```

hope you help me, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could replace your jQuery code with the following.

```
var selectedValues = ["Red", "Black", "Gray"];
$("option").removeAttr('selected');
$.each(selectedValues, function (idx, val) {
    $("option").filter(":contains(" + val + ")").attr('selected', true);
});
```